# Unable to get the Gravitee API gateway respone from CHROME but able to get from POSTMAN

Tags: google-chrome, protocols, postman, ibm-api-management, gravitee

I am trying to hit a GET request which is a Gravitee API Gateway URL on which my web API are exposed. whem I hit the URL from POSTMAN with no headers and no Auth. , I am able to get the response but when I hit the URL from chrome or any other browser, i get this error

**this site can't be reached**

**'ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR'**

Please help me out ? I have tried all the methods to resolve this but still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your gateway is exposed in HTTP2.

A [fix](https://github.com/gravitee-io/gravitee-gateway/commit/e037c17171cdfb663f7c565f9b31a5bd3daf0903) has been provided in latest 1.23.0 of Gravitee.io